Why do I get an error when using custom CSS in Wordpress?
I am trying to get more characters out of a wordpress element in a theme. Currently the line-clamp is limited to 4. I want it to be 6 or none.
When I drop the following into my Wordpress theme's customize additional css section, "line-clamp" is in red:
.elementor-132 .elementor-element.elementor-element-5aa83db4 .elementor-widget-container
{
-webkit-line-clamp: none;
}

Of course if I am inspecting the element on chrome, my edits work but not adding these lines into the css of the theme. Any ideas of how to make this work?


Based on what you wrote and provided information in your question, I have to say that remember -webkit-line-clamp only works in conjunction with display: -webkit-box; and -webkit-box-orient: vertical;. Without these, the line-clamp property won’t function correctly. So, it seems to me by updating your CSS as follow your problem will be solved:
.elementor-132 .elementor-element.elementor-element-5aa83db4 .elementor-widget-container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 6; /* Change this to 6 or none as per your needs */
    overflow: hidden;
}

Please check the live example:


.line-clamp {
      display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 6; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
<p class="line-clamp">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eget orci sit amet dui sollicitudin mollis. Duis cursus eros dui, id iaculis leo faucibus id. Duis vitae facilisis augue. Aenean viverra varius sem, vitae condimentum nisi mollis a. Duis vulputate ante vehicula enim congue tempus sit amet ac ante. Donec non libero sit amet massa porttitor rutrum at quis ipsum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nulla eleifend tempus orci, at dictum augue. Nunc ut sapien vitae nisi commodo vehicula. Nunc et tristique ipsum, et luctus ante. Maecenas tincidunt mi libero, vel fermentum mauris eleifend vitae. In dapibus a ex vitae placerat. Mauris ante dolor, facilisis quis enim eget, convallis aliquam erat.</p>



I guess it is related to your selector, in case you are using elementor, use advanced -> custom CSS and use these lines:
selector .class-of-paragraph {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 6; 
    overflow: hidden;
}

If it is not working, please provide more information. Then, I will be able to help you and update your question.

Thank you. I added a screenshot to my original question of how the css edit you suggested is displayed. You can see box-orient and line-clamp arent being recognized. No idea why.

@AdamD are you saying the CSS doesn’t work or just that the custom css system shows a couple of properties in red?

I am putting the code in the custom css section of the theme

You have to put it in the elementor widget custom CSS. since it includes a selector and only applies to the specific widget, not all websites. Can you please mention the name of widget you are using?
